# PHP Scandir Cloud Folder

Tags: php, cloud, scandir

I Would like to know how i could do a simple `scandir` of a folder in a cloud storage, or if it's even possible.

```
<?php
$dir = "C:/wamp64/www/test";
$a = scandir($dir);
$files = array_diff($a, array('.', '..'));
file_put_contents("C:/wamp64/www/test.txt", "");
foreach ($files as $key) {
    file_put_contents("C:/wamp64/www/test.txt","$key \r\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
?>
```

I have this code currently working fine, but my cloud path is `L:\2017` and putting those values will just say **No such file or directory**

Any help appreciated, and sorry for the inconvenience!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
<?php
$path = '\\2017\somepath\';

$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$drive_letter = "L";

system("net use ".$drive_letter.": \"".$path."\" ".$pass." /user:".$user." /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");
$location = $drive_letter.":/somepath/your_directory";

if ($handle = opendir($location)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    echo "$entry";
    } 
    closedir($handle);
}
?>
```